# Leetcode question Most Common Word in javascript. I am unable to set properties in my object

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, object

I am taking the LeetCode challenge [819. Most Common Word](https://leetcode.com/problems/most-common-word/):

> Given a string `paragraph` and a string array of the banned words `banned`, return *the most frequent word that is not banned*. It is **guaranteed** there is **at least one word** that is not banned, and that the answer is **unique**.
>
> The words in `paragraph` are **case-insensitive** and the answer should be returned in **lowercase**.
>
> #### Example 1
>
> **Input:** `paragraph = "Bob hit a ball, the hit BALL flew far after it was hit."`, `banned = ["hit"]`
> **Output:** `"ball"`

This is my code:

```
var mostCommonWord = function(paragraph, banned) {
    let words = paragraph.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    let unbannedwords = words.filter((word)=> word !== banned[0] );
    let map = {};
    console.log(unbannedwords)
    for (let i = 0; i < unbannedwords.length; i++) {
        count = 0;
        for (let j = i + 1; j < unbannedwords.length; j++) {
            if (unbannedwords[i] === unbannedwords[j]) {
                count++;
                map[unbannedwords[i]] = count; 
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(map)
    let obj = Object.values(map)
    let max = Math.max(...obj);
    
    function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
        return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
    }

    return getKeyByValue(map, max);
};
```

Output `console.log`:

```
[
  'bob',  'a',
  'ball', 'the',
  'ball', 'flew',
  'far',  'after',
  'it',   'was'
]
{ }
```

I don't why properties are not being from the loop in `map` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `split(" ")` call will leave the punctuation in, so you'll have both "ball," and "ball" in the resulting array. Obviously this will make your code miss some equalities.

To resolve this, change this line:

```
let words = paragraph.toLowerCase().split(" ");
```

to:

```
let words = paragraph.toLowerCase().match(/\w+/g);
```

A second issue occurs with how you set the `map` values. Currently, you are resetting the count when a word is encountered the second time in the outer loop. Then the first encounter will no longer play a role. Also, the `map` will only register words when they occur at least 2 times (once in outer loop, once in inner loop).

You should make sure to set `map[unbannedwords[i]]` even when there is no next occurrence. The advantage of the map should be that you don't need the second loop, but that the first loop will find the entry in the map and just increment it with one if it already existed.

You'll still have some other things to do, as currently your code is only taking the first banned word into account, i.e. `banned[0]`. In a comment you propose to use `replaceAll(banned, "")`, but that is not how `replaceAll` works. It expects its first argument to be a string or regular expression. Since you pass it an array, the array is turned into one single, comma-joined string, which is unlikely to match anything.

Here is a spoiler solution:

> `var mostCommonWord = function(paragraph, banned) {
>      const words = paragraph.toLowerCase()
>                             .match(/\w+/g)
>                             .filter(word => !banned.includes(word))
>      const count = {};
>      for (const word of words) count[word] = (count[word] ?? 0) + 1;
>      const maxCount = Math.max(...Object.values(count));
>      return Object.keys(count).find(word => count[word] == maxCount);
>  };`

Comment: And, if I add `replaceAll(banned,"")` then I am able to remove all banned words. But still, I am not able to figure out how can I add all unbanned words as `keys` in my `map` object. And increase its value if the condition matches.

Comment: No, that is not how `replaceAll` works.

Comment: But I am getting my desired output in an array. Please check I have updated my code.

Comment: But you are testing it with just one banned word! The thing is that it will not work when you test it with more banned words. I have extended my answer.

Comment: What does this line means `(count[word] ?? 0)`?

Comment: It is the [??](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operator. In older versions of JavaScript you'd use the `||` operator instead. Here, if `word` is not yet a key in `count`, then 0 will be used instead.